# How to debug a hanging job resulting from reading from lustre?

Tags: gdb, state, pid, strace, lustre

I have a job in interruptible sleep state (S), hanging for a few hours.

- can't use gdb (gdb will hang when attaching to the PID).
- can't use strace, strace will resume the hanging job =(

WCHAN field shows the PID is waiting for ptlrpc. After some search online, it looks like this is a lustre operation. The print files also revealed the program is stuck in reading data from lustre. Any idea or suggestion on how to proceed the diagnose? Or possible reason why the hanging happens?

Answer (score 1):

You can check `/proc/$PID/stack` on the client to see the whole stack of the process, which would give you some more information about what the process is doing (`ptlrpc_set_wait()` is just the generic "wait for RPC completion" function).

That said, what is more likely to be useful is to check the kernel console error messages (`dmesg` and/or `/var/log/messages`) to see what is going on. Lustre is definitely not shy about logging errors when there is a problem.

Very likely this will show that the client is waiting on a server to complete the RPC, so you'll also have to check the `dmesg` and/or `/var/log/messages` To see what the problem is on the server. There are several existing docs that go into detail about how to debug Lustre issues:

- https://wiki.lustre.org/Diagnostic_and_Debugging_Tools
- https://cug.org/5-publications/proceedings_attendee_lists/CUG11CD/pages/1-program/final_program/Wednesday/12A-Spitz-Paper.pdf

At that point, you are probably best off to check for existing Lustre bugs at https://jira.whamcloud,com/ to search for the *first* error messages that are reported, or maybe a stack trace. It is very likely (depending on what error is being hit), that there is already a fix available, and upgrading to the latest maintenance release (2.12.7 currently), or applying a patch (if the bug is recently fixed) will sole your problem.